# Seeing current permissions for a file?

Tags: macos, permission

How can I see the permissions for a file (e.g. if I want to recreate those permissions for another file using `chmod`)?

For example after I run `chmod 644` on `foo.txt`, what command, if any, can I run on `foo.txt` which returns `644`?

Comment: You might want to try at http://unix.stackexchange.com if you don't get any answers here. All I know of is `ls -l foo.txt` which will give you the rwxrwx--- string which you can convert to octal yourself (but I guess you know that already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `ls -l` in terminal you get the permission for your file

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 ---  staff   238 Apr 14  2010 images
-rw-r--r--   1 ---  staff  2628 Aug 26  2009 index.html
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 ---  staff   374 Feb 28  2010 simplemvc
```

You can use table below to convert `rwxr-xr-x` to number and vice versa:

[image]

And get more detail [here](http://www.thedumbterminal.co.uk/information/permissions.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the octal permissions from the command line is by using `stat(1)` with a format specifier.

You can read more in the manual page, but the following will give you what you want:

> stat -f "%OMp%OLp" *<file or directory>*

`%OMp` returns the setuid/setgid/sticky bits in octal and `%OLp` the user/group/other permissions in octal.

For example:

```
$ ls -ld Data
drwxr-xr-x  6 mj  staff  204 20 Feb 11:09 Data
$ stat -f "%OMp%OLp" Data   
0755
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I'm aware of that will list all permissions, including ACLs, is simply to use the Get Info command from the Finder on the concerned file.